# What is exactly mocking in unit testing?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, mocking

I am trying to test an http server functionality and this is the first time I get exposed to the notions of mocks, stubs and fakes. I'm reading this book that it says mocking is describing the state of a complex object at a certain moment, like a snapshot, and testing the object as it is actually the real one. right? I understand this. what I don't understand is what is the point of writing unit tests and assertions of certain cases that we fully describe in the mock object. If we set the expectations of arguments and return values on the mocking object, and we test for those exact values, the test will always pass. Please correct me. I know I am missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

Mocks, Stubs or anything similar serves as a substitute for the actual implementation.

The idea of mocks is basically to test a piece of code in a isolated environment, substituting the dependencies for a fake implementation. For example, in Java, suppose we want to test the PersonService#save method:

```
class PersonService {

    PersonDAO personDAO;

    // Set when the person was created and then save to DB
    public void save(Person person) {
        person.setCreationDate(new Date());
        personDAO.save(person);
    }
}
```

A good aproach is creating a unit test like this:

```
class PersonServiceTest {

    // Class under test
    PersonService personService;

    // Mock
    PersonDAO personDAOMock;

    // Mocking the dependencies of personService.
    // In this case, we mock the PersonDAO. Doing this
    // we don't need the DB to test the code. 
    // We assume that personDAO will give us an expected result
    // for each test.
    public void setup() {
        personService.setPersonDao(personDAOMock)
    }

    // This test will guarantee that the creationDate is defined    
    public void saveShouldDefineTheCreationDate() {         
        // Given a person
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setCreationDate(null);
        // When the save method is called
        personService.save(person);
        // Then the creation date should be present
        assert person.getCreationDate() != null;
    }
}
```

In another words, you should use mock to substitute dependencies of your code to an "actor" that can be configured to return an expected result or assert some behaviours.